# How to configure naming strategy for PostgresQuery?

Tags: java, querydsl

Im using Query DSL for my project http://www.querydsl.com/

```
PostgresQuery postgresQuery = 
    new PostgresQuery(dataSource.getConnection(),
    PostgresTemplates.DEFAULT);

postgresQuery.from(tableName).list(tableName.columnOne);
```

Above code executes query like

```
select columnOne from tableName;
```

Whereas its supposed execute like(as per naming strategy configured for JPA)

```
select column_one from table_name;
```

Not sure how to send `entitymanager` properties to PostgresQuery object. Any suggestions ?

Any examples about how to create / use `ProjectableSQLQuery<PostgresQuery>` will also be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

As per the generated query which is a JPQL, your QType seems to be of type

> ( ... extends EntityPathBase<>)

and should be used with JPAQuery.

If you want to work with SQLQueryFactory, you should generate your QTypes using querydsl-maven-plugin which produces QTypes of type

> (... extends com.querydsl.sql.RelationalPathBase<>)

Please read this [doc for details](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.4/reference/html/ch02s03.html)